# Can mapper output keys be routed to a specific node in Hadoop MR

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to process some data in MR and load it into an external system that sits on the same physical machines as my MR nodes. Right now I run the job and read the output from HDFS and re-route individual records back out onto the desired nodes.

Is it possible to define some mapping such that records with key X always go straight to the desired node Y? Simply put, I want to control where hadoop routes post-sorted partitioned groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily.  The only way I know of to affect the physical location of a block of data on the fly is to implement a custom [`BlockPlacementPolicy`](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.5.0/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/blockmanagement/BlockPlacementPolicy.html).  I'll just throw out some ideas for your use case.

- A custom `BlockPlacementPolicy` can route blocks based on the file name
- The file name of a partition can be modified using [`MultipleOutputs`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html) in MapReduce
- Keys can be routed to specific partitions using a custom [`Partitioner`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.html)

It seems like you can get the result you're looking for, but it won't be pretty.